# How to resolve "valueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>"?

Tags: python, valueerror

Getting this error

> valueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type

with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

contract = pd.read_csv('4.CONTRACT_0806.csv')
contractaff = pd.read_csv('5.CONTRACTAFFILIATE_0806.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(contract)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(contractaff)

mergedf = pd.merge('df1','df2',how = 'outer',left_on=['CONTRACT_CONTRACT_ID'])
```

Why is that?

Comment: It looks like you are merging two strings: `'df1'` and `'df2'`.

Comment: Could you please just take a look at your code before posting it?

Comment: You need to merge the variables df1 and df2 not the strings 'df1' and 'df2'.

Comment: Try this `mergedf = pd.merge(df1,df2,how = 'outer',left_on=['CONTRACT_CONTRACT_ID'])`

Comment: Found my mistake; silly, Thank you !

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.